# How to search for a word from array in a char string using strstr

Tags: c++

my problem is with the strstr function, the string and the array that I want to compare this string against.

My initial code looked like this:

```
char t[255];
if (strstr(t, "test") || strstr(t, "test2") || strstr(t, "test3"))
{
    // found
}
```

Where **t** looked something like this:

```
"xxxxxxx oooooo xxxxx testxxx test2xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

This code worked, but I'd like to keep all the search stuff in an array, so i did it like this:

```
const char* list[3][1] =
{
    {"test"},
    {"test2"},
    {"test3"},
}
```

[...]

```
char t[255];
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(list)/sizeof(list)); i ++)
{
    if (strstr(t, list[i][0]))
    {
        // found
    }
```

**t** still looks like:

```
"xxxxxxx oooooo xxxxx testxxx test2xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

but for some reason the code after such a change doesnt work and doesnt find the value from the array even though it should, how can i do that in proper way?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What do you believe happens when you divide `sizeof(list)` by `sizeof(list)`? Also, when the string contains "test2" don't you think the same string must also contain "test" guaranteed, so why search for both? What does that do?

Comment: The first test in `if (strstr(t, "test") || strstr(t, "test2") || strstr(t, "test3"))` will match EVERY string containing `"test"` (including `"test2"`, ...) So the last two comparisons are superfluous. Why `const char* list[3][1]` instead of `const char *list[3];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(list)/sizeof(list)` will always be 1, so you're only checking the first string in your list.  However, that first string should still be found.  You also don't need the second array index -- you could use just

```
const char *list[3] = { "test", "test1", "test2" };

int main() {
    char t[255] = "xxxxxxx oooooo xxxxx testxxx test2xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); ++i) {
        if (strstr(t, list[i])) {
            printf("found!\n");
            break; } }
}
```

Comment: That's a curious formatting of the closing braces. Perfectly readable and condensed.